# Is there a way to customize the on screen keyboard of a text box?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Say I need to write an hexadecimal editor.

I could write my own textbox with my own on screen keyboard.

Or is it possible to change the onscreen keyboard of the regular text box to show only (0-9) (A-F)?

If so, where can I find a sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [InputScopeNameValue enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue%28VS.96%29.aspx). You will need to write your own onscreen keyboard as there is no support for a hexadecimal character only keyboard.